# cakePHP 1.3 - $this->data -vs- $this->Model->data

Tags: model, http-post, this, cakephp-1.3

In my controller i need to verify that some input-values are different form certain db-table-records values.
Example:

An input with a price value, when updated, must be lower then the current price. so what i do is:

```
$this->Model->read(null, $the_id);
//and then:
if($this->data['Model']['price'] >= $this->Model->data['Model']['Price']) do_stuff();
```

It works. but i fear that it's not something that can trust since i found no documentation regard this method.

Would it be right to assume that `$this->data` will always contain the submitted data, and that `$this->Model->data` will always hold the results of a `read()` call (or any model data reading related content)?

Comment: Seems like it is. can anyone verify it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->data (in the controller) represents the POST'ed data from the browser.

$this->Model->data represents the data that is saved to the Database (or set in the model by the controller).

If you were to do:

```
$this->Model->set($this->data);
$this->Model->save();
```

That is the same as:

```
$this->Model->save($this->data);
```

Doing the latter will store the data in $this->Model->data. If you were to manipulate that data in $this->Model->data via a behavior or other `beforeSave()` callback, it will not replicate to the controllers `$this->data` array. So be careful.

So in response to your question:

**Would it be right to assume that $this->data will always contain the submitted data**

*Yes, that is correct*

**and that $this->Model->data will always hold the results of a read() call (or any model data reading related content)?**

*Yes - but you can also store the Model data from a read directly to a variable:*

```
$data = $this->Model->read(null, $id);
```

Just be aware, that the two data arrays are *not* linked, the Model->data will not replicate back to the `$this->data` in the controller. You would need to manually set that in your controller:

```
$this->data = $this->Model->data;
```

Hope this helps.